# Uniquely differentiate UIViews

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have an application where every view controller subclasses from `BaseViewController` (A custom view controller that subclasses from `UIViewController`). I need to differentiate the subviews of a certain view controller's view from each other, from the `BaseViewController`. The application is pretty huge and each subview doesn't necessarily have a `tag`. What other ways are there to differentiate the sub views?

Comment: You can look at any of the properties of the subviews or their types.  So, you could check that the class is a button -- you could get all of the x values of the buttons and choose the left-most one. You could look at the title text of the button -- and so on.

Comment: @LouFranco sorry for the misunderstanding, but when I mean differentiate I mean, I need to be able to find a particular view that my service would eventually tell me what view I need to find, except I need to write a code to essentially match the view on the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

> The application is pretty huge and each subView doesn't necessarily have a "tag". What other ways are there to differentiate the subViews?

That's exactly what the `tag` property is for -- differentiating between views that are otherwise similar, like each button in an array of buttons. You should only need to differentiate between the subviews managed by a single view controller at any given time; any given view should only be known by the view controller that manages its parent view, so the size of the app really doesn't change the `tag` property's utility.

The other obvious way to tell the difference between views is to use the fact that they're distinct objects, each with its own address. For example, say you've got a bunch of similar views representing people on a seating chart, and you want to keep track of which view goes with each person in the chart. One way to do that is to have your view controller maintain a `NSDictionary` where the keys are people and the values are the views.

Comment: What I mean to say when the application is pretty huge is, that I can't go to each view controller now and mark the subviews with tags

Comment: Also, when I mean differentiate I mean, be able to pick one particular view based on "something" other than tag, because at this point its too difficult to go and tag my subviews

Answer (score 0):

XIB and Storyboard files are just XML. You could write a script to load the XML, put in tag attributes and save.  The XML element name tells you what kind of view it is (button, imageView, etc).

Alternatively, if you can have different tags on each load, you can just programmatically tag the subviews in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: its actually a pretty old application and that would mean a storyboard would not be involved in some of the subViews